# Generate and run JAR from Spring Boot project with Gradle doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, build.gradle, executable-jar, gradle-plugin

I have an API project made in Spring Boot with Gradle and it works when I run the application from the IDE, but if I try to compile, build and run the project in a JAR, it doesn't work and I get the following error:

***As additional comments, I am using a multitenant project and the lombok library to simplify the code.*

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'edu.uoc.dslab.api.infrastructure.jpa.SpringDataUsuariRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1812)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Below I expose some part of my code:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'edu.uoc.dslab'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.32'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.15'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.14'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.14'
    implementation(group: 'org.dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: "2.1.4") {
        exclude group: "pull-parser", module: "pull-parser"
    }

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'edu.uoc.dslab.api.DSLabApiApplication'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters={@ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})})
public class DSLabApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DSLabApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**API Controller**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@RestController
@Transactional
@RequestMapping("/endpoint")
public class APIController {
    private final PermissosService permissosService;
    private final ProjecteService projecteService;
```

**Service**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@Service
public class PermissosServiceImpl implements PermissosService {

    private final UsuariService usuariService;
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface SpringDataUsuariRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {


}
```

I have tried multiple annotations, I suspect that the problem comes from the gradle configuration, since the project works from the IDE, and I can make different requests to the API, but the problem is when generating the artifact and trying to run the JAR.

Comment: What commands are you using to build and then run the jar file? You're customizing the `jar` task which is unusual for a Spring Boot application. You should be able to use the `bootJar` task in its default configuration instead.

Comment: Could you send me any example with bootJar? Thanks for advance!

Comment: To build the jar file I'm using by default IntelliJ as IDE.